# Javascript function defined in the head is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitButton').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/text/', 
               $('#myForm').serializeArray(), 
               function(data, status) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    $('text').html(document.getElementById('message').innerHTML);
                    $('sentiment').html(json.result.sentiment);
                    $('confidence').html(json.result.confidence);
                    console.log(json.result.sentiment);
                    console.log(status+"\n");
                });
        });
});
</script>

<section class="container content-section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">

            <div class="row control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                    <form id="myForm" method=POST action="http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/text/">

                        <p>Enter your sentences:</p>
                        <textarea rows="5" type=text name="txt" class="form-control" placeholder="Sentences to detect" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary align-right" type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This part should work when the page is loaded, but it doesn't response at all.

EDIT: The script does not execute at all, what we get instead is a GET request to the url: ...index.html/?txt=[inputfrommyform] and nothing changes on the page, instead of the page even hitting the target POST request server.

Just updated according to the comments. Thank you!

The error we get from Chrome Inspect is still

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't response": Does this code execute on page load? If yes, is a POST request send? If yes, do you receive a reply? If no, what is the status of the POST request? Use your browser's developer console (press [F12]) to find out.

Comment: as @le_m stated, more information is needed. Essentially you want us to help you debug what is wrong, but debugging requires seeing the browsers reaction and tracking the root cause of the unintended reaction. So we need more info on what the browser is saying when it tries to execute your code.

Comment: Is $('#submitButton') actually there?

Comment: You need to prevent the default action of the form. So `$('#submitButton').submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: :( it's still not working. We're still getting the url: .../index.html?txt=hello instead of any POST request to the actual API.

Comment: Are you actually including jquery?

Comment: You need to include the jQuery lib before code in your script tag.

Comment: I don't see you including jQuery anywhere so of course $ will be undefined

Comment: Thank you so much !!! It is working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Four issues:**

1. You need to listen to the submit event of #myForm instead of #submitButton which doesn't emit such an event.
2. Your post callback receives an already parsed JSON object, parsing again fails as a string is expected but an object given.
3. You need to prevent the default action on form submit by returning false from your submit event handler.
4. You need to include jQuery *before* your script.

**Fixed code:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
      $.post('http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/text/',
        $('#myForm').serializeArray(),
        function(json, status) {
          $('text').html(document.getElementById('message').innerHTML);
          $('sentiment').html(json.result.sentiment);
          $('confidence').html(json.result.confidence);
          console.log(json.result.sentiment);
          console.log(status + "\n");
        });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>

<section class="container content-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
      <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
          <form id="myForm" method=POST action="http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/text/">
            <p>Enter your sentences:</p>
            <textarea rows="5" type=text name="txt" class="form-control" placeholder="Sentences to detect" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary align-right" type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```